# Scrapy adds undesired prefix link when following link

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
2019-03-17 17:21:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://www.google.com/www.distancesto.com/coordinates/de/jugenheim-in-rheinhessen-latitude-longitude/history/401814.html> (referer: http://www.google.com/search?q=Rheinhessen+Germany+coordinates+longitude+latitude+distancesto)
2019-03-17 17:21:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <404 http://www.google.com/www.distancesto.com/coordinates/de/jugenheim-in-rheinhessen-latitude-longitude/history/401814.html>
```

so instead of following 'www.distancesto.com/coordinates/de/jugenheim-in-rheinhessen-latitude-longitude/history/401814.html' it adds 'http://www.google.com/' before and obviously returns in a broken link. this is beyond me and I can't understand why. the response does not have that, I even tried to return after 22 character(undesired preifx length) and it erased part of the real link.

```
class Googlelocs(Spider):


name = 'googlelocs'
start_urls = []

for i in appellation_list:
    baseurl =  i.replace(',', '').replace(' ', '+')
    cleaned_href = f'http://www.google.com/search?q={baseurl}+coordinates+longitude+latitude+distancesto'
    start_urls.append(cleaned_href)



def parse(self, response):


    cleaned_href = response.xpath('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div[1]/h3/a').get().split('https://')[1].split('&')[0]
    yield response.follow(cleaned_href, self.parse_distancesto)


def parse_distancesto(self, response):
    items = GooglelocItem()

    items['appellation'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/p/strong)').get()
    items['latitude'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td)').get()
    items['longitude'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td)').get()
    items['elevation'] = response.xpath('string(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td)').get()

    yield items
```

here is the spider.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in parse and try to figure out what went wrong from inside the debugger. Also, this will never work because google will block you.

Comment: what do you mean it will never work? I get the full response body from google.

Comment: They will start showing captchas after a certain number of requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

href = response.xpath('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div[1]/h3/a/@href').get()

this was the correct path to obtain the href from google. Also I had to accept the link masked by google without trying to modify it to be able to follow into it.